# How to pass information between viewControllers that do not segue to each other?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a pretty complicated function generating a value in one view controller (lets call it `firstVC`). This value is used in `firstVC` but I would also like to utilize this value in other view controller at a later time (which we'll call `thirdVC`). I know I could set up a protocol to rerun the function, but this would just take extra time and I would rather just pass the value. No segue exists between `firstVC` and `thirdVC` and the time at which `thirdVC` will be opened and utilize the value is unknown and will be at some later time. (I can still get to `thirdVC` by seguing: `firstVC` -> `secondVC` -> `thirdVC`). I thought one could set it up as follows:

```
//In firstVC
var currentVal: String = "Hello"

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let thirdVC: thirdVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC")
    thirdVC.passedValue = currentVal
}
```

With `passedValue` being a variable living in `thirdVC`. This, however, does not pass any information as when I try to check the `passedValue` on the `thirdVC`'s `viewDidLoad()` it is empty... I also try checking the value later via a button (to ensure that `viewDidLoad()` running before the info is passed isn't the issue) and it is still empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Also see: [Detailed SE documentation on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201707121111354890919) for both Obj C and Swift (Also sorry for the wrong DV as dupes are good and you have shown your effort. I was hitting UV and somehow hit DV. Corrected now)

Comment: What about a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value when instatiating the vc, can be done by using didSet as seen below.

```
var currentVal: String = "Hello"

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let thirdVC: thirdVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC")
    storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC")
    thirdVC.passedValue = currentVal
    self.present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

third vc ..

```
class thirdVc: UIViewController {

    var someValue: String? = nil

    // MARK: - Value to set when passed
    var passedValue: String! {
        didSet {
            self.someValue = passedValue
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.someValue) // "Hello"
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not want to use `self.present` as I do not want to go to the `thirdVC` at the same time that the info is passed. Also, I tried using the code you answered with and it is still giving me a nil value in the `thirdVC`

Comment: Try ```let thirdVC: thirdVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "thirdVC") as! thirdVC ```

Could be you're not holding the actual view controller as reference and can't access it's properties. 

I don't really understand what you mean not wanting to go the view at the same time info is passed. Why would you pass data to a view if you're not using it? 

If you need to store a value over the lifecycle in an application write to user defaults, core data or realm. 

You're question was about passing data to a view without segue which my answer will do.

Comment: You can't hold a value in a viewcontroller if you aren't holding it  in memory.

Comment: I would like to hold the information because the function to obtain it is complicated and slow (relatively speaking) and that function is run on the viewDidLoad of the `firstVC`. I want that information to be used later whenever the user gets to the `thirdVC` (without needing to rerun the function). You are saying I should utilize one of those three methods (defaults, CR, or realm) instead?

Comment: If you need to hold a value accessible throughout the app there is several different approaches. You could make the function you are performing accessible through out the app by assigning the func as a method to a class you share as a singleton. You could assign values to user defaults.
Or something like this: 

class MyAccessibleData {
  static let sharedInstance = MyAccessibleData()
  var myValue: String?

  func myBigDataFunc () {
      self.myValue = "Hello"
  }
}
// in vc3
let helloString = MyAccessibleData.shared.myValue // Hello